# Setting email signatures globally in Google Apps for Enterprise

Tags: g-suite

How can I globally set HTML email signatures, which include unique user data (name, phone number, etc.), without using the command line or a browser plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do it from the Admin console.

However the same effect can be done through [the API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html), specifically the "[Updating Signature Settings](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_signature_main)" call. Through that you can take a dump of user data and create a bunch of calls to this API to overwrite any User signature settings with what you desire to force.

Which is not what you're looking for, as you're looking for a GUI element that takes variables like ${Fullname}. Google hasn't built such a tool, though it clearly is doable given they have an API for it. There may  be third party tools that accomplish this.

Comment: I'd looked into the maps api, but found no solution there for setting unique user data - I guess I may have to look into an smtp based solution.